# Cargo patch to redirect registry to local path without having to call cargo login

Tags: rust, registry, patch, rust-cargo

**My issue:**
Rust crate A (and several other crates) depends on crate B (both A and B are local crates). However, since we wanted to share crate A on a private registry (Artifactory), it was required to also publish crate B to a registry (since it is not allowed to depend on local/relative path dependencies on something you publish, which makes sense). So in the project manifest the dependency to crate B is set like this:

```
crate_b = { version = "0.1.0", registry = "artifactory"}
```

To accomplish this I have set up the config.toml like this:

```
[registry]
global-credential-providers = ["cargo:token"]

[net]
git-fetch-with-cli = true

[registries]
artifactory = { index = "sparse+https://my_artifactory_url" }

[package]
publish = "artifactory"
```

I was surprised to find that when doing `cargo build` I then needed to first have called `cargo login` to setup the needed credentials. But since there is a lot of places in our CI/CD setup where we call cargo build in different docker containers, I had hoped that this would not be needed until I decided to actually run `cargo publish` to push the crate to the registry (which is something we for now only need "on-demand" and not for every build).

**I have tried the following:**
The source code for crate_b still resides in our project. So I though that I could use `[patch]` to tell cargo to fetch it from a local path instead of from the registry. I have set it like this in the `cargo.toml` workspace manifest:

```
[patch.artifactory]
crate_b = { path = "./src/crate_b"}
```

But it still tries to connect to the registry and requires me to do cargo login.

I have also tried all sorts of combinations of `--locked`, `--frozen`, `--offline` as options to `cargo build`, but that also did not help.

**My question:**
Is there any way I can run a normal cargo build with a registry dependency (that has been overwritten by a manifest patch), without having to setup my cargo token/credentials?

**Bonus question:**
I thought that "cargo login" simply crates the `credentials.toml` file for you. However, I tried to just copy in the resulting `credentials.toml` file to the .cargo folder, but that didn't seem to be enough. Does `cargo login` do more than just create the `credentials.toml`?

I hope that some of you awesome Rustacean are able to help me out :)